# Directory locked!

Tags: process, sudo, virtualbox, kill

I have been trying to install virtualbox using this command:

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox.qt
```

But I am getting this error:

```
E: Unable to lock directory /var/cache/apt/archives/
```

I have been trying to find the answer here and have already tried:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock
sudo dpkg --configure -a

sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock    
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock

ps aux | grep apt
kill -9 processnumber
```

But none of them work.

Comment: Do other `apt` commandos like `apt-get update` work?

Comment: @Tobias after updating, now getting this:Media change: please insert the disc labeled
 'Ubuntu 14.04 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20140417)'
in the drive '/media/cdrom/' and press enter

Comment: When do you get this message? If you run `sudo apt-get install virtualbox.qt` or when? Are you sure, virtualbox.qt is the correct package name? I can't find it in http://packages.ubuntu.com.

Comment: @Tobias YES! It is the correct package name :\ I have tried sudo apt-get install virtualbox and sudo apt-get install virtualbox.qt both

Comment: You shouldn't just blindly "try" random things. "Unable to lock directory" means another process is using it. (You have been told [in your similar question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/452638/how-can-i-solve-unable-to-lock-the-administration-directory-var-lib-dpkg) on askubuntu that Ubuntu updates automatically.) If you just kill the process using SIGKILL, it won't terminate normally and won't remove eventual lock files. You'll then have to manually remove those. You should instead stop or close *properly* the program/update manager that is modifying your package database.

Comment: @Leiaz this question is solved thank you!!

Comment: @Leiaz plus I mentioned the reason, I have asked the question if u read the whole question :D

Comment: @Tobias THANK YOU! I am really new to UBUNTU and sorry for lame questions :( but u helped me a big time just found my solution :D

Comment: Your welcome. What was the problem?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/454447/directory-locked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `lsof /var/cache/apt/archives/` you can check, which process still has this folder open. With this you may find the process which holds the lock.